# Is there a implementation-agnostic way to determine the memory cost of a new insertion into an std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have an `std::unordered_map` in my program. I would like to restrict it to never used any more than `n` bytes.

My idea was to keep track of how much memory it's using and if an additional insertion would exceed the limit, to then remove the element at `unordered_map::begin()`.

But to do so, I would need to know the cost of inserting the next element. Would the `sizeof(std::unordered_map<Key, T>::node_type)` be this value? From what I read on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map it's not clear to me if the `node_type` *contains* the values, or whether they might be pointers etc.

Due to the questions in the comments:

1. I am already using a custom allocator for the `std::unordered_map`. However, that can only tell me the cost of a specific insertion after it has occured, not prior. I see no guarantee in the reference docs that every element requires the same amount of memory. For example, I imagine that additional buckets may be requested a bit like a `std::vector` requests twice as much storage for its element type each time.
2. My specific use case is using it as a transposition table within a minimax algorithm. In my case, the key for the map is the current game-state being evaluated, which is fairly large, so I'd like to limit the amount of memory the unordered_map is using. I could simply ignore the transposition table (at the cost of an additional check that the element exists *prior* to retrieving), but...
3. I'm planning on storing the #times an element was requested in the transposition table, storing it with the `T` in the map, so that I can remove the least accessed one. I've contemplated using an `std::map` instead for the ordering, but I believe I still face the same issue of determining the cost of an additional insertion.

Some of the above is irrelevant to the core of my question though. Is it possible to determine, ahead of time, the memory cost of an additional insertion into an `std::unordered_map`?

EDIT:

An additional problem I've found is that a call to `std::unordered_map::erase` doesn't make a call to the used allocator to free the memory. I.e., the implementation is free to hold onto previously requested memory so it doesn't need to keep requesting more.

I suppose I could create a copy of the map, with only the elements that aren't to be removed, but this sounds like a fairly costly exercise, considering I'd need two copies (or at least 2 copies worth of memory allocation). I might need to roll my own.

Comment: I think you could use a custom _Allocator_ (fifth template parameter) for this. Btw `begin()` is not necessarily pointing at the oldest element in the map.

Comment: You can easily limit any container to a number of elements, but not actual byte size. Unless you know the *exact* implementation of the map. What is your actual and underlying problem? Where does this requirement come from? Please ask about your actual and original and underlying problem directly instead, otherwise your question just becomes another [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Also please be careful when just removing the `begin` element of a an unordered map. Because it's unordered, there really isn't any specified order of the elements. There's no guarantee that the elements are in insertion order. In fact, `begin` could return an iterator to the *last* element you added to the map.

Comment: My thought is the same as Ted's - implement an allocator that can report how much it has allocated and not yet freed, and use that in your wrapper class that holds the map.  Note that you'll end up briefly going over-capacity: you can't make a callback from your allocator to make space as needed  because attempting to modify the map re-entrantly will break spectacularly.

Comment: Is this some sort of cache?  Just checking the number of elements might be good enough, although you still need a way to determine the oldest if that's the one you want to evict.

Comment: If you want an implementation-agnostic way to control memory consumption of an unordered map then you may want to use boost intrusive unordered map.

Comment: Thanks all, I've updated my question to address your comments.

Comment: I'd go by `if (um.size() * sizeof(elem_t) > max_byte_size) { /* magic goes here */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the C++ library that will give you this precise information, for a very simple, trivial reason. Even if you can have `std::unordered_map` give you the precise number of bytes used by the entries themselves, and the unordered map's internal overhead, that means utterly nothing. That's because each entry in the map, both the key and the value, is free to dynamically allocate its own memory. Adding an entry to a key or a map may either copy or move a key or a value, and have unspecified memory use overhead resulting from that.

If you have have an unordered map with a thousand empty `std::string`s that's going to take up a vastly different amount of memory than another unordered map with a thousand `std::string`s, but each one containing the complete contents of a randomly chosen chapter from "Harry Potter And The Philosopher's Stone".

And even if every container in the standard C++ library could produce, on demand, the number of bytes that it takes up, and `std::unordered_map` would add its own overhead to the amount, and returned it, that won't be of much help with a `std::unordered_map` of your own objects, that use their own dynamically-scoped objects, for their own use.

Something what you're looking for must be implemented in the core of C++ itself, and not just the C++ library. There's nothing like that, in C++.

But all is not lost: the unordered map can tell you its `size()`, in constant complexity. And it is reasonable to conclude that the actual memory used to store an unordered map is proportional to the number of entries in that unordered map. Presuming that the actual amount of memory taken up by each entry is the same, on average, taking the map's `size()` can give you a heuristic, fairly accurate, estimate on how much memory it takes up, which you can use for your own purposes.

Comment: Thanks @Sam. I've been investigating the usage pattern via my custom allocator, and yeah, after a certain point it seems fairly consistent. So I might instead look at restricting it to a count of elements, rather than total memory usage.

Comment: A custom allocator can track the overhead used by the unordered map itself, but that may not be the same thing as the amount of memory used by the entire unordered map, for the reasons stated.

Comment: “That's because each entry in the map, both the key and the value, is free to dynamically allocate its own memory” and “Presuming that the actual amount of memory taken up by each entry is the same, on average, taking the map's `size()` can give you a heuristic, fairly accurate, estimate on how much memory it takes up, which you can use for your own purposes” are conflicting assumptions. If OP’s request is intended to consider just the implementation of the map itself and exclude the memory of the subject data, then the conclusion drawn from the former statement is invalid…

Comment: … but, if the former statement is a basis for not being able to track the memory, then the latter presumption is unwarranted. Any one item could consume an arbitrary and disproportionate amount of memory.

Comment: For clarity I was only interested in the overhead of the unordered map. I know how much allocation I need for my stored objects, or can otherwise find out.